# How to set array as default value on props (Vue composition api + Typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue-composition-api

With Vue 3 (composition api) + Typescript , I am trying to set default values on the props after defining them with an interface.
I get a typescript error when I try to set default value `[]` on one of the props. How can I set a default empty array?

```
<script setup lang="ts">

interface IProps {

  title: string;
  things: any[];
  productUrl: any;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<IProps>(), {
  title: "",
  things: [],            //<-- error (se below)
  productUrl: "",
});
```

The error:

```
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '(props: Readonly<IProps>) => any[]'.
```

It also says:

```
The expected type comes from property 'things' which is declared here on type 
'InferDefaults<Readonly<IProps>>'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Object or array prop defaults must be returned from a factory function.  The Vue docs mention this under [prop validation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation)

```js
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<IProps>(), {
  title: "",
  things: () => [],
  productUrl: "",
});
```

Comment: You can also use `things: Array` since that is also a function that returns an empty/new array

Answer (score 4):

You should return the empty array using a function :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

interface IProps {

  title: string;
  things: any[];
  productUrl: any;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<IProps>(), {
  title: "",
  things: ()=>[], 
  productUrl: "",
});
```

For the standard syntax :

```js
const props =defineProps({
  things:{
      type:Array,
      required:true,
      default:()=>[]
    }
})
```